# Ajax and Combox generated

Tags: jquery, ajax

i need some help.

I have a table create by displaytag with:

```
<div id="contentAccionFormativa" class="displayAF">           
                    <display:table id="displayAF" name="${accionesFormativasList}"                                                              
                                   htmlId="justifAfList"
                                   class="displayTagTable" 
                                   uid="accionFormativa">    
                        <display:column titleKey="asociarJustificante.display.af.header.checkbox"                                    
                                        class="tdBorderFirst center"
                                        headerClass="firstTh"
                                        style="width: 2px;" >                           
                            <form:checkbox id="checkAf" path="listaIdAccionesFormativas" value="${accionFormativa.idAfExteInteIdConv}"/>
                        </display:column>
                        <display:column titleKey="asociarJustificante.display.af.header.descripcion" class="lastTh center" >
                            ${accionFormativa.codAF}
                        </display:column>

                        <display:footer>
                            <tr><td colspan="2" class="firstTh lastTh right"></td></tr>
                        </display:footer>
                    </display:table>
                </div>
```

I try get count checkbox with:

```
jQ('#justifAfList :checkbox').click(function() {
        alert(jQ("input:checked").length);
    });
```

It´s works fine, but when i was generated table with ajax with:

```
 jQ.each(data.ajaxResult.accionesFormativas, function(i,value){
                    firstTd = "<td class='tdBorderFirst center' style='width: 2px;'><input id='checkAf' type='checkbox' value=" +value.idAfExteInteIdConv+ " name='listaIdAccionesFormativas'><input type='hidden' value='on' name='_listaIdAccionesFormativas'></td>";
                    jQ('#justifAfList > tbody:last').append("<tr class='odd'>" + firstTd + "<td class='lastTh center'>" + value.codAF +"</td></tr>");
                });
```

the jquery function only capture the click on the first checkbox.

Someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delegate the event to an existing object:

```
jQ('#justifAfList').on('click','input:checked',function() {
    alert(jQ("input:checked").length);
});
```

Or, in case you work with a version lower than 1.7, use 'live'.